# Daemon service state check. "$?" always returns 0

Tags: bash, unix, sh, daemon

I have file "sleepdaemon" which launches python program as service
I run this script:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sleepdaemon start
```

but when I check the state $?=0 always
this is how i check

```
  if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Process is running"
  fi
  if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Process is not running"
  fi
  if [ "$?" -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "Process is not running"
  fi
```

What's the problem ?

Comment: What does `sleepdaemon` return?

Comment: sleepdaemon runs python program that does time.sleep(10)

Comment: @user3057314: that's not the question; the question is what does `sleepdaemon` **return** as its exit status?

Answer (score 2):

The value of `$?` gets reset after every test, so you either need to save it in a variable before testing, or use a `case ... esac` statement.

Comment: I try this, but its also 0. I need to check if the program that was started with sleepdaemon ran withouth errors.

Comment: @user3057314: Does `sleepdaemon` have a mechanism for reporting the exit code of the program it invokes (e.g., in a log file)? Does it invoke the program repeatedly? Can you modify the program to report its exit code through a custom mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` returns the result of the command, or 1 if it can't run it.  `?` is set for EVERY command:

```
if (( $? == 0 )); then
    echo "Process is running"

elif (( $? == 1 )); then
    echo "Process is not running" >&2

elif (( $? == 2 )); then
    echo "Process is not running" >&2
else
    echo "Unknown exit code $?" >&2
fi
```

Use `(( ... ))` for arithmetic comparisons - it is easier and safer.  You should always have a default long-stop, and you should report errors to stderr, not stdout.

If `$?` is always zero, then check the documentation for `sleepdaemon` (I tried, but can't find a return code documented anywhere).

Comment: Your code doesn't work as intended: As in the OP's code, using `$?` in a test (including an arithmetic one) causes its value to be set to the outcome of that test. In the case at hand your `if` statement will only work if `$?` happens to be `0` - any other value will cause the `(( $? == 1 ))` branch to be entered, because the initial test - `(( $? == 0 ))` - sets `$?` to `1`, because the test returned "false" (indicated with exit code `1`).